# mod_rewrite RewriteRule anomaly

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm preparing rewrite rules for my site. And I'm faced problem when target URL contains characters like "%3A". 
Apache mod_rewrite just removes "%3" when rewrites url.

For example I need rewrite url

```
/primed-white-mdf-skirting+architrave/
```

to

```
/Products/Decorating+Interiors/Mouldings/Skirting/c/1000589?q=%3AtopSellers%3AColour%3AWhite&text=#
```

I have generated rule for this. Here it is:

```
RewriteRule ^primed-white-mdf-skirting\+architrave/ /Products/Decorating+Interiors/Mouldings/Skirting/c/1000589?q=%3AtopSellers%3AColour%3AWhite&text=# [R=301,L,NE]
```

So rewrite pass to:

```
 /Products/Decorating+Interiors/Mouldings/Skirting/c/1000589?q=AtopSellersAColourAWhite&text=%23
```

Why this happens? Please help

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `%` signs in the rewritten portion of the directive? Changing them to `\%` should work.

Comment: escaping and adding [NE]-key works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `%` otherwise `%3` is considered a `back-reference` of captured group from `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteRule ^primed-white-mdf-skirting\+architrave/ /Products/Decorating+Interiors/Mouldings/Skirting/c/1000589?q=\%3AtopSellers\%3AColour\%3AWhite&text=# [R=301,L,NE,QSA,NC]
```